# Reading entire property file loaded by PropertySource in spring bean

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

I've a spring bean which loads the property file depending upon their availability as shown below:-

```
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:user.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file:./config/user.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
```

The property file is getting loaded, but when I try to read entire property file in one go via :-

```
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("user.properties");
```

then I only get the properties from classpath. Do spring provide any mechanism to read all properties in one go?

Answer (score 1):

That code of yours doesn't do what the annotations do. You have a couple of annotations that declare what to do. That logic isn't present *at all* in the code snippet.

There's no magic, if you want the same result, you need to translate the declarative aspects of those annotations in code (i.e. reading the classpath file then the file one and check if it exists and then merge those properties).

If you're ok to get extra keys, you could also simply inject the `Environment` as `@PropertySource` is going to update that.

Comment: OK, is there any way I can get all properties from a file injected in Resource object (provided by spring)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, may be this may help someone.
Since I need to override the properties file contained in jar with external properties file (if present in  specified folder) also I need to read entire property file in one go.
I've leveraged the spring behavior of loading last property read.

```
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file:./config/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
```

Now if application.properties is present in ./config/ location then it'll override application.properties from classpath.

In main application.properties I've defined from where the external properties should get loaded i.e.

```
config.location=./config/
```

**./config/** attribute can be overridden in case of production and test environment.

After this I've defined a bean to load all properties files (import statement skipped):-

```
@Component
public class PropertiesConfig {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesConfig.class);

private final String[] PROPERTIES_FILENAMES = { "prop1.properties", "prop2.properties",
    "prop3.properties" };

private String configLocation;

private Map<String, Properties> configProperties;

@Autowired
public PropertiesConfig(@Value("${config.location}") String configLocation) {
this.configLocation = configLocation;
configProperties = Arrays.stream(PROPERTIES_FILENAMES)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(filename -> filename, this::loadProperties));
}

public Properties getProperties(String fileName) {

if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName) || !configProperties.containsKey(fileName)) {
    logger.info(String.format("Invalid property name : %s", fileName));
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        String.format("Invalid property name : %s", fileName));
}
return configProperties.get(fileName);
}

private Properties loadProperties(final String filename) {
final Resource[] possiblePropertiesResources = { new ClassPathResource(filename),
    new PathResource(getCustomPath(filename)) };
final Resource resource = Arrays.stream(possiblePropertiesResources)
    .filter(Resource::exists).reduce((previous, current) -> current).get();
final Properties properties = new Properties();

try {
    properties.load(resource.getInputStream());
} catch (final IOException exception) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}

logger.info("Using {} as user resource", resource);

return properties;
}

  private String getCustomPath(final String filename) {
    return configLocation.endsWith(".properties") ? configLocation :                configLocation + filename;
   }
   }
```

Now you have a bean containing all the properties file in map which can be injected in any bean and can be overridden for any environment.